# Query Custom Post Type posts by Keyword/url slug

Tags: query

I am running an affiliate shop with around 10k products and I am trying to build Landingpages for SEO/SEM purposes. Those pages should contain a title, some text and related products.

I would like to query the products by url slug. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'title'          => 'contains url slug' // add something like 
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    endwhile;
}
else {
    _e( 'No products found' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

The product data is something that I get via remote APIs (from different merchants). Those responses don't contain any categories or taxonomies that I could use for this.

Alternative: Is there a way to display "search results" for the slug in the URl on this page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`name` parameter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) in your arguments ex:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'posts_per_page' => 12,
  'name' => 'slug'
);
```

but this will only match the post with that same slug.